# How to ask for permissions?

Tags: objective-c, macos

How do I create a dialog like the following one in Objective-C?
[Mac OS X authorization http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/5900/screenshot20100522at153.png](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/5900/screenshot20100522at153.png)

I'm quite new to Objective-C, and I need root access to a file in the /etc directory.

Thanks!!
Yvan

Comment: Being new to Objective C - it might be worth noting that Apple tend not to use /etc and use other ways of setting things on boot e.g. launchd

Comment: actually, it's to alter the /etc/hosts file automatically. My application checks the file, puts the missing rules wich are required for us in a string, and tries to alter the file. But I'm always getting the "Access Denied" error.

Comment: I know that, and that's required. I'm writing a hosts patcher/toggler for the saurik signature server.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Authorization Concepts](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/02authconcepts/authconcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH205-TP9) and the code sample: [BetterAuthorizationSample](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004207-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).